# Why some APIs implemented Serializable interface but did not declare serialVersionUID?

Tags: java

I'am confused when I look the source code of `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`, why does it implement `Serializable` but no `serialVersionUID` was given in it?

[[image: serializable]]

Comment: Because the Spring authors chose not to define one. serialVersionUID is not necessary for serialization to work. It's needed if you plan to support backward serialization compatibility when evolving the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to declare it but you can omit declaring it, default mechanism take care it for you.

> If a [serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value.